# How to use replaceAll() method in StringBuffer?

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I need to replace multiple words in a string buffer. So I am looking for a `replaceAll` method in `StringBuffer`.

So do we have it in `StringBuffer`?

String method:

```
str2 = str1.replaceAll(regex, substr);
// (This is String method, I need like this in StringBuffer)
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to do it in `StringBuffer`? Doesn't  `stringBuffer.toString().replaceAll(regex, substr);` do the job?

Answer (score 5):

There is no such method on `StringBuffer`. Perhaps the following will help:

```
StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer("whatever");
// to get a String result:
String str2 = str1.toString().replaceAll(regex, substr);
// to get a StringBuffer result:
StringBuffer str3 = new StringBuffer(str2);
```

Comment: Glad it helped! You can also mark this answer as accepted (with the green check mark) and/or mark it as useful (using the up arrow) :-)

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a bit more optimized, as it does not create new strings or string buffers.
Suppose you want to replace str1 with str2.

```
StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer("yourString");
int startIndex = strBuf.indexOf(str1);
while(startIndex != -1){
    strBuf.replace(start, start + str1.length(), str2);
    start = strBuf.indexOf(str1, start + str1.length());
}
```

With this method, you find the index of each occurance of str1 in your buffer and replace it one by one with str2. The method indexOf(String str, int index), returns the index of the first occurance of str starting from index.